# How to create a DataFrame from mapPartitions iterator?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with an `id` column. I would like to do some computations on the rows for each id (not only aggregations) and output a new DataFrame with one row per id, containing the results of the computations.

I am trying to do this by repartioning on the id and then using `mapPartitions`:

```
df.repartition(col("id")).mapPartitions(iter => {
    val dfSubset = // iter to DataFrame?
    // Computations on dfSubset
})
```

But how do you create a DataFrame from `iter`? The goal is to then make the computations on the DataFrame `dfSubset` containing all the rows for an id.

EDIT:

`repartition(col("id"))` will not create 1 partition per `id`. We should use `groupBy("id")` instead.

Comment: what exactly is the requirement. if you want array of data frame you can go for a `randomsplit`

Comment: @victordeplasse `repartition(partitionExprs: Column*)` will not create as many partitions as the distinct number of ids, it will only create `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`(default 200) partition and the value of `id` will be hashed to perform the partitioning. We can avoid repartitioning . and add the per-id processing code as parts of mapPartitions logic?

Comment: @DaRkMaN Thank you. I thought repartition would create one partition per id. In this case it is better to use groupBy("id") then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is to do a `groupBy` on `id` and then define your own [User Defined Aggregate Function](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html). If you need all columns you can construct a struct of said columns and pass to your aggregate function.

```
df
.groupBy("id")
.agg(myUdaf(struct(df.columns.filter(_ != "id").map(col(_)):_*)).as("result")).show()
```